# Calculate volume enclosed by cylinder and paraboloid (integration).

Tags: integration, volume

I need to calculate the volume enclosed by:
$$x^2 + y^2 = z, \space y = x^2, \space z=0, \space y = 1$$

The shape of the volume I get gets me confused. It is a paraboloid ($x^2 + y^2 = z$) intersected with cylinder ($y = x^2$) and limited by specific $z$ and $y$ plains. When I tried drawing this I saw that the volume is not limited by the "upper" $z$ plain, therefore it seems to be infinite. Did the lecturer provide us with "wrong" conditions, so the volume is infinite?

Am I right? If yes, how can I calculate the volume if I change my previous condition ($z = 0, \space y = 1$) to $0\le z \le 1$? I tried approaching this "updated" problem, but also didn't have any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** The answer including the integral solution was posted - see below. The whole problem was caused by me thinking about the volume "inside" the paraboloid, while the task was to calculate it "outside", enclosed by the cylinder.

Comment: [Image for illustration](https://i.snag.gy/fq2ZiU.jpg "generated by Wolfram Mathematica").

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I did it the correct way now; how do you create plots like this? Is this Wolfram? This can be really useful for me in the future.

Comment: Yes, Wolfram Mathematica. They has a free online version at https://sandbox.open.wolframcloud.com , or https://tio.run/#mathematica (doesn't support image output unfortunately)

Comment: Thanks for your input, that is really useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look first at the $xy$-plane (the bottom). The condition limits the area $D$ between $y=x^2$ and $y=1$. It is bounded in $(x,y)$. Now look at what happens along the vertical $z$ axis. It says: take those points $(x,y,z)$ that are between $z=0$ and $z=x^2+y^2$. The set (and the volume) is finite, it is between two surfaces ($xy$ plane and the paraboloid).

[image]

Try to split integration as
$$
\iint_D\int_{z=0}^{z=x^2+y^2}\,dz\,dxdy.
$$

Comment: My first try is something like: $\int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{0}^{x^2} dy \int_{0}^{x^2 + y^2} dz$.

Comment: @Sqoshu The second part is wrong. It is not really between $y=x^2$ and $y=1$ (i.e. above the parabola), you got it below the parabola between $y=x^2$ and $y=0$.

Comment: If I think correctly the $y$ value changes from $x^2$ to $1$, so shall the integral be "reversed" like: $\int_{x^2}^{1}dy$?

Comment: Does this "step by step" approach always work with integrals like this (going thru $(x,y)$, then focusing on $(x,y,z)$)? It seems much more logical now.

Comment: @Sqoshu Typically, there are two principles to split a triple integration to iterated: (1) double-single, and (2) single-double. Here we applied the first one (it looks like summing up a spaghetti looking small parts to the whole), but the second one is often used as well, it reminds slicing a bread. The choice between them depends most on how the set description looks like.

Comment: Wait, doesn't the $\int_{-1}^{1} f(x)dx$ always give 0, no matter what is under the integral?

Comment: @Sqoshu No, try $\int_{-1}^1x^2\,dx$. It is zero for an odd function though.

Comment: Ok, so finally I got: $$\int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{x^2}^{1} (x^2 + y^2) dy = \int_{-1}^{1} (\frac{1}{3} - \frac{x^6}{3})dx = \frac{1}{3} (x - \frac{x^7}{7})|_{(-1, 1)} = \frac{1}{3}(1 + \frac{1}{7} + 1 - \frac{1}{7}) = \frac{2}{3}$$

Comment: @Sqoshu Wait, $x^2$ should also be integrated, $\int_{x^2}^1 x^2\,dy=[x^2y]_{y=x^2}^{y=1}$.

Comment: You are right, because it is integration, not differentiation; my bad..

Answer (score 2):

First of all the volume is not infinite because it is bounded at $z=2$.
Draw the figure on a $xy$-plane at $z=t$ where $0\leq t\leq2 $ you will see that the figure gets closed.
$\int_{0}^{2}S(t)dt$ where $S(t)$ is the area enclosed by $y=1,y=x^2$ and $x^2+y^2=t$.
Keep in mind that you will have to consider two cases separately when $0\leq t\leq1 $ and $1\leq t\leq2 $.

Comment: Why should I consider the two cases separately? What changes at $t = 1$?

Comment: The area is divided in two pieces.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to help from **A.Γ.** and **Chris2006**:

It turns out that the volume is enclosed and can be calculated. The answer was accepted. Using the hints given there:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{x^2}^{1} dy \int_{0}^{x^2 + y^2} dz = \int_{-1}^{1} dx \int_{x^2}^{1} (x^2 + y^2) dy = \int_{-1}^{1} (x^2 y + \frac{y^3}{3})_{y =(x^2, 1)} dx= \int_{-1}^{1} (x^2 + \frac{1}{3} - x^4 - \frac{x^6}{3})dx = (\frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{1}{3} x - \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{21})_{x =(-1, 1)} = \frac{88}{105}$$